# How to send file info in invoke method of SignalR in angular?

Tags: angular, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to send a file to the server through invoke method but it doesn't hit that Method in server

```
async fileUpload(username: string, files: any){
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("recipientUsername",username);
  formData.append('FormData', files);
return this.hubConnection.invoke('FileUpload',{recipientUsername: username,formData})
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

}

here in FileUpload method I'm trying to save the file to the message and show it to the user live. But it doesn't hit by the client side call.

```
 public async Task FileUpload(FileDto createFileDto)
    {
        var username = Context.User.GetUsername();

        if(username == createFileDto.RecipientUsername.ToLower())
            throw new HubException("You cannot send file to youself");
        
        var sender = await _userRepository.GetUserByUsernameAsync(username);
        var recipient = await _userRepository.GetUserByUsernameAsync(createFileDto.RecipientUsername);

        if(recipient == null) throw new HubException("Not Found User");
        
        var message = new Message();
        string groupName ="";
        if(createFileDto.FormData != null)
        {
            if(!Directory.Exists(AppDirectory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDirectory);
            
            var fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(createFileDto.FormData.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(AppDirectory, fileName);
            var contentType = createFileDto.FormData.ContentType;
            var fileFormat = Path.GetExtension(createFileDto.FormData.FileName);

            using(var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await createFileDto.FormData.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }

            message = new Message
            {
                Sender = sender,
                Recipient = recipient,
                SenderUsername = sender.UserName,
                RecipientUsername = recipient.UserName,
                IsFile = true,
                Content = "",
                FileName = createFileDto.FormData.FileName,
                FileFormat = fileFormat,
                ContentType = contentType,
                FilePath = path
            };

            groupName = GetGroupName(sender.UserName, recipient.UserName);

            var group = await _messageRepository.GetMessageGroup(groupName);

            if (group.Connections.Any(x => x.Username == recipient.UserName))
            {
                message.DateRead = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
            else
            {
                var connections = await _tracker.GetConnectionsForUser(recipient.UserName);
                if (connections != null)
                {
                    await _presenceHub.Clients.Clients(connections).SendAsync("NewMessageReceived",
                        new { username = sender.UserName, knownAs = sender.KnownAs });
                }
            }
            _messageRepository.AddMessage(message);
        }

        if(await _messageRepository.SaveAllAsync() && groupName != "")
        {
            await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("NewMessage",_mapper.Map<MessageDto>(message));
        }
    }
```

here is the class I'm passing in the method

```
public class FileDto
{
    public string RecipientUsername { get; set; }
    public IFormFile FormData { get; set; }
}
```

any help is much appreciated..

Comment: Hi @Shanto Siddiq, could you please share the detailed code? Besides, what if you change `formData.append("file", file, file.name);` to `formData.append("FormData", file, file.name);`?

Comment: Hi @Rena I've changed that as you suggest but now It doesn't hit the method. I've edited and tried to provide the whole code.

Comment: Not yet. Actually your problem is cannot hit the server side, so you need to share your client side whole code instead of server side code.

Comment: You can see the fileupload function from the first code segment.